Recognizer not getting my voice in my python code with speech recognition module
import pyttsx3
import distutils
import speech_recognition 
engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty("rate",170)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def takeCommand():
    r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.energy_threshold = 300
        audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit= 5)
    try:
        print("Understanding...")
        query = r.recognize_goo(audio,language='en-in')
        print(f"you said : {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Say that again")
        return "None"
    return query

I was trying to access recognize_google but in suggestions it won't showing and also i was trying with other module recognize_bing but in the output it won't recognizing my voice but the other lines of code working except that line please help me out thanks.
It was giving output like:
Say that again
Listening...
Understanding...
Say that again
Listening...
Understanding...
Say that again
Listening...

